# SVG distorted in browser

Tags: web, svg, adobe-illustrator

all!

I made a SVG file in Illustrator to display on a web page.
However, a corner of the stroke is distorted.

should look like:
http://i515.photobucket.com/albums/t356/bpf2010/png_zpsabaf2c87.png

does look like:
http://i515.photobucket.com/albums/t356/bpf2010/svg_zps76da6311.png

Does anyone have any idea about how to fix it?

Thanks,
BPF

Comment: Hard to tell without the svg, and what you can change. Couple of quick thoughts could be the strokes line-cap, and the order of path drawing (so which bit is on top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Illustrator, select your artwork, go to "Object" and select "Expand.." and select the checkbox for the "Stroke".

Finally, Export to SVG.